# Elasticsearch - sort by geo distance with gauss decay function

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, distance, geo

"location" is a geo_point field that I have mapped correctly.
Should I explicitly tell elasticsearch to sort by distance? 
The response shows that all documents have the same score "1".

If there are documents with geo_point ("location" field in my example)
that is empty: lat lon 0.0000 0.0000 - will this brake all scores?
This is in the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

> geo distance sorting does not support configurable missing values: the distance will always be considered equal to Infinity when a document does not have values for the field that is used for distance computation.

Should I understand it like that: "the distance will always by considered equal to Infinity **FOR ALL RESULTS** when a **SINGLE** document does not have values for the field... ? So one document with bad data renders the whole search result useless???

```
GET users/users/_search
{
  "explain": true, 
   "query": {
     "function_score": {
       "gauss": {
         "location": {
           "origin": [-34.60368, -58.38156],
           "scale": "5km",
           "offset": "2km"
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Another attempt:

```
{
  "explain": true,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": -34.60368,
          "lon": -58.38156
        },
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The response explains the sorting as infinity:
and all scores are "null":

```
    "total": 1643,
    "max_score": null,
"sort": [
          "Infinity"
        ]
```

Should I combine the gauss decay function and the sort from the 2 examples above?